# Android Studio Build Fail (do not have that dependency); Error: Program type already present: common.utility.EEG

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am having trouble building in Android Studio. This is the error: `Error: Program type already present: common.utility.EEG`

I attempted the solutions for similar problems however I could not get it to work. I tried to look for common.utility.EEG but could not find it.

```
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
    Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
    Program type already present: common.utility.EEG
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:471)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:335)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:39)
```

These are my dependencies for reference:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.isaac-udy:Kfilter:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.zomato:androidphotofilters:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:easypreferences:1.0.6'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+'
    implementation files('libs/Algorithm_1.5.jar')
    implementation files('libs/Basicutility_1.3.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-net-3.5.jar')
    implementation files('libs/d2xx.jar')
    implementation files('libs/eegproduct_1.5.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jmatio-1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/MQTT_1.0.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `multiDexEnabled true` into your `build.gradle` under the `defaultConfig` scope

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}

public class YouApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: I implemented it but the error remains. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks! I was able to fix my problem.